# How to derive the equation relating the Laguerre Gaussian mode to the Hermite Gaussian mode of a laser beam

Tags: optics, laser

[image]

Please help me derive the last equation, any tips are welcome. The $u^\text{LG}$ refers to Laguerre-Gaussian mode while $u^\text{HG}$ refers to the Hermite-Gaussian mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exponential factors dependent on $r$ and the $z$ dependent part of the profiles are easily matched up, it is enough to just check the part involving the Hermite and Laguerre polynomials.
For this keys step, [Beijersbergen et. al. (1993)](https://doi.org/10.1016/0030-4018(93)90535-D) (which I assume is the paper where your expression comes from) cites a [1991 paper by Abramochkin and Volostnikov](https://doi.org/10.1016/0030-4018(91)90534-K) for a relation between the Hermite and Laguerre polynomials,
$$
\begin{multline}
\sum_{k=0}^{n+m}(2i)^k P_k^{(n-k,m-k)} (0) H_{n+m-k}(x)H_k(y) \\
= 2^{n+m}\times\begin{cases}
(-1)^m m! (x+iy)^{n-m} L_m^{n-m}(x^2+y^2) & \text{for } n\geq m\ ,\\
(-1)^n n! (x-iy)^{m-n} L_n^{m-n}(x^2+y^2) & \text{for } n \leq m\ ,
\end{cases}
\end{multline}
$$
where
$$
P_k^{(\mu,\nu)}(t) =\frac{(-1)^k}{2^k k!}(1-t)^{-\nu}(1-t)^{-\mu} \frac{d^k}{dt^k}[(1-t)^{k+\nu}(1+t)^{k+\mu}]\ .
$$

The main idea for proving of this formula is to cook up a generating function for both the Laguerre polynomials and the Hermite polynomials, then match up the two series to produce a relation between them.

A possibly cleaner presentation of this fact can be found in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0377-0427(00)00681-6). There the following generating functions are given for the two type of polynomials,
$$
\begin{gather}
\exp\left(2t_1 x + 2t_2 y - t_1^2 - t_2^2\right) = \sum_{n_1 = 0}^\infty\sum_{n_2 = 0}^\infty \frac{t_1^{n_1}t_2^{n_2}}{n_1!n_2!} H_{n_1}(x)H_{n_2}(y)\\
\begin{aligned}
\exp\left(s_1 z + s_2 \bar{z} - s_1 s_2\right) & = \sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s_1^{m}s_2^{n}}{m!n!} (-1)^n n! z^{m-n} L_n^{m-n}(z \bar{z}) \\
 & = \sum_{m=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{s_1^{m}s_2^{n}}{m!n!} (-1)^m m! \bar{z}^{n-m} L_m^{n-m}(z \bar{z})
\end{aligned}
\end{gather}
$$
If we set $t_1 = \frac{1}{2}(s_1 + s_2), t_2 = \frac{1}{2i}(s_2-s_1)$ and $z = x + i y, \bar{z} = x-iy$, then the two generating functions will become identical.
To match up the corresponding terms between the expansion in terms of $t_i$ and $s_i$, we can first write
$$
\begin{align}
t_1^{n_1} t_2^{n_2} & = \frac{1}{2^{n_1+n_2}i^{n_2}} (s_1 + s_2)^{n_1} (s_2 - s_1)^{n_2} \\
& = \frac{1}{2^{n_1+n_2}i^{n_2}} s_2^{n_1+n_2}\left(1 + \frac{s_1}{s_2}\right)^{n_1} \left(1 - \frac{s_1}{s_2}\right)^{n_2}.
\end{align}
$$
The last two factors dependent on $s_1/s_2\equiv t$ can be expanded as a Taylor series in $t$, so the $s_1^m s_2^n$ term in the generating function should have contributions from the $n$-th order term in the Taylor expansion for $t_1^{n_1} t_2^{n_2}$ where $n_1 + n_2 = m$.
You can now check that the $(2i)^{k}P_k^{(n-k,m-k)}(0)$ factor comes from the coefficient of the Taylor series and the factors of $2$ and $2i$ in the transformation between $s_i$ and $t_i$. Finally, the factorial prefactors in $b(n, m, k)$ are due to the factorials in the generating function as well as normalization factors for the polynomials. (Note that the Hermite and Laguerre polynomials defined above using generating functions have a different normalization from the conventional definition.)

The proof by Abramochkin and Volostnikov is essentially the same as the proof above, except that the generating function relations are rewritten term-wise using (essentially) Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it was crisp and clear. My knowledge of special functions is a little rusty so I was struggling. Anyway, thanks and cheers!